# Show a Copying-files dialog/form while manually copying files in C#?

Tags: c#, file, user-interface, dialog

I am manually copying some folders and files through C#, and I want to show the user that something is actually going on. Currently, the program *looks* as if its frozen, but it is actually copying files.

I would think there is already a built-in dialog or form that shows the process, similar to copying/moving files in windows explorer. Is there anything like that available, or will I have to create everything from scratch?

Also, would this be the best method to show the user that something is actively going on?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is one built in from the **Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO** Namespace. Don't let the name scare you, it is a very underrated namespace for C#. The static class `FileSystem` has a `CopyFile` and `CopyDirectory` method that has that capability.

[FileSystem Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.aspx)

Pay Close attention to the `UIOption` in both the `CopyFile` and `CopyDirectory` methods. This <strike>emulates</strike> displays the Windows Explorer copy window.

```
FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile, UIOption.AllDialogs);
FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory, UIOption.AllDialogs);
```

Comment: Wow, it really is underrated. I've never heard of that namespace. I had to create a recursive method in order to copy a directory and its sub-directories using the "File" namespace. This is so much simpler!

I do not have the VB package installed for Visual Studio. I assume I would have to install it in order to get access to the namespace, yes?

Comment: It's part of the .net framework. Just add the Microsoft.VisualBasic reference to your project and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did, but from that namespace I only see the "VBCodeProvider" class from it. Updating VS with VB to see if I get more stuff.

Comment: Ah, reference! I only added a "using" on top. Works fine now, thanks!

Comment: Very nice approach! But how can I show one same dialog for several copy/move operations? If I call CopyFile/MoveFile for each single operation, several dialogs will open each saying "copying/moving 1 element"—that does not make a very user-friendly impression to me. Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `BackgroundWorker` thread you can show a progress dialog. You will need to use a thread if you don't want to lock the UI.

The example on this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58(v=VS.100).aspx) shows how to update a progress indicator. In this case it's on the main application form, but you can create your own dialog for this.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the user experience you'd like to provide. You can use Windows APIs to show the standard copy dialog; however, I believe that your application will still seem unresponsive.

I'd recommend something like this:

```
// WPF
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
   foreach(String file in filesToCopy)
    {
        // copy file here

        // WPF UI Update
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // progressBar Update
        }); 
    }                    
});

// WinForms
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    foreach(String file in filesToCopy)
    {
        // copy file here

        // WinForms UI Update
        Form1.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // progressBar Update
        }); 
    }               
});

// in either case call
t.Start();
```

This allows you to use your existing file copy logic, and still provide a nice responsive user interface.