# Windows 10 Copy Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there any access to the copy dialog of Windows 10 for my WPF application?

[image: Windows 10 Copy Dialog]

I want to copy files into a folder, if there are files with the same name, I want to show the copy dialog of Windows 10.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5729808/993547

Comment: See Here, Nice answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041211/show-a-copying-files-dialog-form-while-manually-copying-files-in-c

Comment: Did not found that while I was searching. @Ryan this is exactly what I was searching for, thanks a lot!