# Use Windows Native Copy and Move Progress Bar from C# Windows Form App

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I was wondering if we could give the open source community this logic, using which the C# Windows Form App Developers can integrate the copy and move native window box like this -

[image]

Can we even do this?
Because whatever threads I have came across while searching for this provide their own Progress Bar in Windows App.

Comment: give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041236/1132334) a try... old, but maybe still around and working

Comment: It is [readily available in the framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127960(v=vs.110).aspx) in everybody's favorite utility namespace.

Comment: any c# code example would help me a lot, if you guys can help me in writing it. I tried writing using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO; http://i.imgur.com/oSc58YT.png

Answer (score 5):

What comes unnatural is that you have to add a reference to the assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in your C# project.

[image]

And then add the correct namespace at the top of your .cs file:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
```

Here is the "C#" code (that really is nothing more the a call to the correct method) to invoke [`FileSystem.CopyDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127960(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileSystem.CopyDirectory(
        @"c:\src",
        @"c:\dst",
        UIOption.AllDialogs,
        UICancelOption.DoNothing);
}
```

And that will generate the desired eye candy for you with having to deal with any Progressbar handling on your own.

[image: progress dialog]

Comment: Now I don't need to do replace, skip or any other System.IO error handling in code :)